# Can't find registry key on Windows 10 Education N to deactivate start menu web search

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

I have Windows 10 Education N, version 21H2. I'm trying to turn off the web search function of the start menu by editing the registry, but I don't know which key I have to edit in my Windows version, and other posts I've found are for a different one. I've read it can also be done via Cortana but I have her deactivated and don't want to turn that on again.

I've tried the method suggested [here](https://www.bennetrichter.de/en/tutorials/windows-10-disable-web-search/), by adding the key "DisableSearchBoxSuggestions" to this path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows", but it sadly didn't work.

I also tried adding the same key to this path instead "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" with no result either.

After reading through [this article](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/23/how-to-disable-web-search-in-windows-10s-start-menu/), the only option that worked was using the Group Policy Editor instead of the registry. I still don't know how to do this through the registry but my problem is solved nonetheless.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Here's how to on regular Win 10; don't know if it's valid for EDU version. https://www.bennetrichter.de/en/tutorials/windows-10-disable-web-search/

Comment: @Peregrino69 - There is no difference. Only `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` is required.

Comment: @Ramhound - that's good to know :-)

Comment: @Ramhound But it will have to be put in the correct path, right? The posts I've seen have paths for the key that my registry doesn't have.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Didn't seem to work, but thanks

Comment: @Owny - You have to create them if they don't exist.  You can also just use the Local Group Policy editor and set the policy and as a result the key will be created.

Comment: Please don't respond in comments, rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771391/edit) your question. That way it stays up-to-date and all the relevant info is readily available. I'd put in something along the lines "This (link here) suggests modifying registry key <the suggested registry key> but I don't have it".